# css and js are not applying to my page?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

i am not able to apply my js(script.js) and css(style.css) to my page.i have include them in my common.xhtml as:

```
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet name="common-style.css" library="css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
 href="${request.contextPath}/static/css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/
 ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/
 ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="${request.contextPath}/static/js/script.js"></script>

</h:head>
```

and called in my login.xhtml as:

```
 <ui:composition template="/faces/global/common.xhtml">
```

here is my login.xhtml code goes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

```
 <!-- Messages must be global here, to show bad credentials -->
 <h:messages globalOnly="true"/>

<!-- Id's must not be changed to support spring security check -->
<ui:composition template="/faces/global/common.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="userBean">
     <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            User : 
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{loginController.user.userId}" 
                size="20" required="true"
                label="user" >
            </h:inputText>

            <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />

            Password : 
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginController.user.password}" 
                cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                label="password" >
            </h:inputSecret>

            <h:commandButton type="submit" id="login" value="Login"  action="#{loginController.login}" />

        </h:panelGrid>



      </h:form>

 </ui:define>



</ui:composition>
```

and the page code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/provider-pay/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/provider-pay/resources/common-style.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/provider-pay/static /css/styles.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/provider-pay/static/js/script.js"></script></head><body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">

    !-- Start Header --&gt;
    <div class="Header clearfix">
        <!-- Document wrapped -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="brand_logo">
                    <a href="#">prime 340b</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">system</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="organization.html">organization</a>   </li>
                                 <li><a href="bin_management.html">BIN management</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">old BIN management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">client</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="payor.html">payor</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="hc.html">health center</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="view_hc.html">view health centers</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="prescribed_panels.html">prescriber panels</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">price file</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">invoices</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="group_file_config.html">group file config</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">pharmacy</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="view_parmacy.html">View Pharmacies</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">prescribers</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">vendors</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="chain_pharmacy.html">chain pharmacy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="wholesalers.html">wholesaler</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">switch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">price verification</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">price checking</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="view_package_size.html">package size page</a></li>
                                         </ul>
                                   </li>
                                   <li><a href="prime_vendor.html">Volume Discounts</a></li>
                                </ul>
                             </li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!-- end of navigation -->
        </div><!-- end of wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Header -->
    </div>

    <div id="content">
  <form id="userBean" name="userBean" method="post" 
  action="/provider-pay/faces/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="userBean" value="userBean" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>
 User : 
</td>
 <td><input id="userBean:name" type="text" name="userBean:name" size="20" /></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>

Password : 
</td>
  <td><input id="userBean:password" type="password" name="userBean:password"
  value="" /></td>
  <td><input id="userBean:login" type="submit" name="userBean:login"
   value="Login" /></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" 
   id="javax.faces.ViewState"
   value="-89546852753845925:2642184477073405002" autocomplete="off" />
   </form>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
     <!-- start footer -->
        <div class="footer">
            <p>All rights are reserved</p>
        </div>
     <!-- end footer -->
        </div>

    </div></body>
 </html>
```

can any one help in this.
thank you

Comment: Are the files loaded correctly if you hit the generated path in your browser directly?

Comment: yes for css coming like:<html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}...etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
    <h:head>
       <link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <script src="resources/js/default.js"></script>
    </h:head>
```

or

```
 <h:body>     
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css"/>
   //other code
 </h:body>
```